# Database structure for a complex pricing matrix

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working on a custom eCommerce solution which requires a fairly complex pricing matrix to figure out prices.  Currently orders are all made in person, so the client is using a massive excel spreadsheet to figure out prices.

Three factors dictate the price of a product:

1. The product type (5 product types)
2. The product size (~30 different sizes: 10x6, 20x10, etc)
3. The product border (3 border sizes: 2,3,4)

Here are some example prices:

- Product type A with dimensions 5x12 with a 4 inch border costs 100
- Product type A with dimensions 6x14 with a 4 inch border costs 120
- Product type A with dimensions 6x14 with a 3 inch border costs 110
- Product type B with dimensions 6x14 with a 3 inch border costs 200
- Product type B with dimensions 6x14 with a 4 inch border costs 220

Currently there is no formulaic/systematic approach to how the numbers work, its just a massive spreadsheet.  Does anyone have any pointers in how approach this problem from a database perspective?

Comment: `Spreadsheet == table`, unless the spreadsheet also has formulas in it.

Comment: Are there only these 5 types of products? If that is the case, then you just could just create a table with 5 rows with these parameters.

Comment: I just updated my post, but there are 5x30x3 = ~450 combinations with different prices.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table covers all deliverable type/height/width/border combinations, try five columns (six if you want an id):

```
id long, // optional
ProductType varchar[16], 
Height float, 
Width float,
Border float,
Price float
```

And then find it with

```
SELECT Price 
FROM tbl
WHERE ProductType = @t
AND Height = @h
AND Width = @w
AND Border = @b;
```

Comment: So this product type table would have a row for every possible price combination?

Comment: @Roeland - yes unless you can provide a rule that would allow cpombioning several rtows into one - which you have said you cannot do

Comment: You've already said that "there is no formulaic/systematic approach to how the numbers work." So either there has to be one row per combination, or you have to come up with a formula.

Comment: I gotcha, that makes sense.  Though I think I may call it something like a price lookup table.  Because they are really just customizations to a particular product.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes.  You're looking up the deliverable type/height/width/border combinations and finding the given price, as defined on this non-formulaic table.

Comment: I'll suppose that the 450 (5x30x3) combinations are already defined in the spreadsheet, as something like this, so next export the spreadsheet into this table.